# wordpress login_redirect and template_redirect generates a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I've a strange behaviour with the filter login_redirect and the action template_redirect.

I visit a page with a course grid and if I'm not logged-in, I'll be redirected to the auth page (wp-login.php). The action hook **template_redirect** was fired.

Now I type my login into the form and submit it. Now the filter **login_redirect** is fired and if I'm not an admin, I'll be redirected to the course grid page, not to the dashboard.

Here is, where the strange thing happen. I don't see the course grid page, I'll be redirected again to the auth page (wp-login.php). At this point I run into a loop.

If I debug the output of the function **is_user_logged_in()**, it returns a *false*.

But if I browse to the course grid page, after the first login, I'm logged-in. I can see the courses ... So the login seems to work, but I don't know why I'm redirected everytime again to the auth page.

Do I use the wrong actions or filters?

```
function tspb_secure_bp_sites() {
    global $post;

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && get_option( 'tk_course_grid_page', 0 ) == $post->ID ) {
        auth_redirect();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'tspb_secure_bp_sites' );

function tspb_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    if ( is_null( $user->roles ) ) {
        return $redirect_to;
    }

    $grid_page = get_option( 'tk_course_grid_page', null );

    // Redirect to dashboard, if admin
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
        return $redirect_to;
    }

    // Redirect to home url, if course overview is not set
    if ( empty( $grid_page ) || get_post_status( $grid_page ) == false ) {
        return home_url();
    }

    return get_permalink( $grid_page );
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'tspb_login_redirect', 99, 3 );
```

Comment: Why not implementing logging in system inside the template redirect? I believe right now both are fired..

Comment: I tried it and disabled the login_redirect filter. The user will be redirected to the dashboard.
Here I hooked into the admin_init action, where I redirect the user to the grid, if the user has no admin role. Still in the loop ... :-(

`add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && $_SERVER['DOING_AJAX'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {
$grid_page = get_option( 'tk_course_grid_page', null );
$permalink = empty( $grid_page ) ? home_url() : get_permalink( $grid_page );
wp_redirect( $permalink ); exit;
} } );`

Comment: Are you sure `current_user_can()` and `$_SERVER['doing_ajax']` returns what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it works properly. We've found what the problem was: Varnish caching. The page was cached and the php wasn't executed. - Big thanks for your help! :-)